# Trying to install wordpress on Ubuntu

Tags: wordpress

I was trying to install WordPress on ubuntu by following this https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#4-configure-database

but stuck at step 4, whenever I run this

```
mysql> GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,ALTER
    -> ON wordpress.*
    -> TO wordpress@localhost
    -> IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

I get

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 4
```

I know I'm doing something wrong just don't know where

please help
thanks

[Sreenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BibsN.png)

Comment: Just a heads-up, this is more of an SQL issue than an Ubuntu issue, no big deal, though. For future reference it'd be nice if you'd copy and paste the code or console output and wrapped them in backticks (`) instead of linking screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The `IDENTIFIED BY {password}` bit is unnecessary. If the MySQL user has not already been created, then:

```
CREATE USER 'wordpress'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
```

Then you can assign permissions:

```
GRANT ALL ON `wordpress`.* TO 'wordpress'@'localhost';
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding. I managed to start WordPress on my pc but whenever I try to upload a plugin I get this ''' The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.''' and while trying to upload new theme I get '''Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2021/04. Is its parent directory writable by the server?'''

Comment: These are different issues to the one you originally reported. That said, PHP has the maximum upload size set to 2MB by default. You will need to increase this to something more realistic for your situation. Next, ensure the directory where WordPress is installed has `755` permissions. For example: `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/wordpress`. It is also useful if the Wordpress directory is owned by Apache: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/wordpress`.